# SQLAlchemy - How to count distinct on multiple columns

Tags: python, mysql, sql, orm, sqlalchemy

I have this query:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Serial, DatumOrig, Glucose) FROM values;
```

I've tried to recreate it with `SQLAlchemy` this way:

```
session.query(Value.Serial, Value.DatumOrig, Value.Glucose).distinct().count()
```

But this translates to this:

```
SELECT count(*) AS count_1
    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT 
           values.`Serial` AS `values_Serial`, 
           values.`DatumOrig` AS `values_DatumOrig`,
           values.`Glucose` AS `values_Glucose`
          FROM values)
    AS anon_1
```

Which does not call the count function inline but wraps the *select distinct* into a subquery.

My question is: What are the different ways with SQLAlchemy to count a distinct select on multiple columns and what are they translating into?

Is there any solution which would translate into my original query? Is there any serious difference in performance or memory usage?

Comment: Have you asked MySQL to EXPLAIN the two queries to see if the results are significantly different?

Comment: @GordThompson Not yet, good idea. However I know that MySQL loses connection if I run the second query even with just the subquery, select distinct part. Which suggests that the SQLAlchemy version overburdens my MySQL server while the first native version returns after a minute (~32 million records).

Comment: Are any of the columns nullable? If so, then at least one difference between the 2 queries is that the "native" query (one with `count(distinct ...)` does not count rows where serial, datumorig, or glucose is NULL. The latter counts all rows produced by the subquery, which includes (distinct) rows with NULLs. Does not explain the performance difference though, probably.

Comment: Looking at https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tTEQytCcsv8Xu1CGVPt1k4/0 it looks like the "count from subquery" causes a temporary table to be used, even for such small data amount, and if that's an on-disk temporary, then it might at least partly explain the performance diff given your large dataset.

Comment: @IljaEverilä Yes, I've just ran the `Explain` on them too. Also interesting that even the subquery loses the connection for me. The difference for that is that an index is used in both cases but with the select distinct(...) one it says `Using index; Using temporary` while with the count(distinct(...) version it is `Using index for group-by (scanning)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First off, I think that `COUNT(DISTINCT)` supporting more than 1 expression is a MySQL extension. You can kind of achieve the same in for example PostgreSQL with `ROW` values, but the behaviour is not the same regarding NULL. In MySQL if any of the value expressions evaluate to NULL, the row does not qualify. That also leads to what is different between the two queries in the question:

1. If any of `Serial`, `DatumOrig`, or `Glucose` is NULL in the `COUNT(DISTINCT)` query, that row does not qualify or in other words does not count.
2. `COUNT(*)` is the cardinality of the subquery `anon_1`, or in other words the count of rows. `SELECT DISTINCT Serial, DatumOrig, Glucose` will include (distinct) rows with NULL.

Looking at `EXPLAIN` output for the 2 queries it looks like the subquery causes MySQL to use a temporary table. That will likely cause a performance difference, especially if it is materialized on disk.

Producing the multi valued `COUNT(DISTINCT)` query in SQLAlchemy is a bit tricky, because [`count()`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/functions.html#sqlalchemy.sql.functions.count) is a generic function and implemented closer to the SQL standard. It only accepts a single expression as its (optional) positional argument and the same goes for [`distinct()`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.distinct). If all else fails, you can always revert to [`text()`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.text) fragments, like in this case:

```
# NOTE: text() fragments are included in the query as is, so if the text originates
# from an untrusted source, the query cannot be trusted.
session.query(func.count(distinct(text("`Serial`, `DatumOrig`, `Glucose`")))).\
    select_from(Value).\
    scalar()
```

which is far from readable and maintainable code, but gets the job done now. Another option is to write a custom construct that implements the MySQL extension, or rewrite the query as you have attempted. One way to form a custom construct that produces the required SQL would be:

```
from itertools import count
from sqlalchemy import func, distinct as _distinct

def _comma_list(exprs):
    # NOTE: Magic number alert, the precedence value must be large enough to avoid
    # producing parentheses around the "comma list" when passed to distinct()
    ps = count(10 + len(exprs), -1)
    exprs = iter(exprs)
    cl = next(exprs)
    for p, e in zip(ps, exprs):
        cl = cl.op(',', precedence=p)(e)

    return cl

def distinct(*exprs):
    return _distinct(_comma_list(exprs))

session.query(func.count(distinct(
    Value.Serial, Value.DatumOrig, Value.Glucose))).scalar()
```

Comment: Thanks for the summary Ilja. One problem, the query you've provided creates: `SELECT count(DISTINCT Value.Serial, Value.DatumOrig, Value.Glucose) AS count_1` without the `FROM values` part, thus gives the `Unknown table 'Value' in field list` error.

Comment: Silly mistake, sorry about that... Naturally SQLA has no idea what to select from, if you just give it a text fragment :)

Comment: No problem, thanks for the correction. One additional and interesting information worth to add, that this query does actually return a Query object, while the `.count()` gives back a scalar.

Comment: Yeppers. There's `Query.scalar()`, which is a handy way to get the first column of the first row in these kind of queries. Another thing worth mentioning: what ever you pass to `text()` is put in the query verbatim. If that "something" comes from an untrusted source...

Comment: `If that "something" comes from an untrusted source...` - Ouch, this is only for inner logic and temporarily hard coded values, but I planned to make it injectable for later advancements with outher dynamic inputs. This is SUPER informative, thank you!